# What is the effect of setting (or not) .NET CLR version in ASP.Net Core?

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, clr, unmanaged, application-pool

What is the point of setting "No Managed Code" .NET CLR version for an IIS Asp.NET Core application pool?

[image: No Managed Code for .NET CLR version]

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?tabs=aspnetcore2x) says that

> ASP.NET Core runs in a separate process and manages the runtime.
>   ASP.NET Core doesn't rely on loading the desktop CLR. Setting the .NET
>   CLR version to No Managed Code is **optional**.

Since it is **optional**, what are the drawbacks of keeping the default **v4.0**? Why the documentation explicitly instructs to set it to "No Managed Code"? It's not very clear whether there are performance concerns around this particular configuration.

Comment: Keeping ASP.NET 4.x means IIS worker process will still try to load ASP.NET related supporting libraries (aspnet_isapi.dll or webengine4.dll) into memory, while your ASP.NET Core apps won't use them at all. That extra memory usage should be avoided.

Comment: @LexLi: Please post that as an answer.

Answer (score 11):

When you specify .NET CLR version as 4.0 for an application pool, IIS loads into its worker processes some ASP.NET supporting libraries (like `aspnet_isapi.dll` for classic pipeline mode, and `webengine4.dll` for integrated mode). Such increases memory usage and attack surface, and might also have other impact.

Therefore, if you only run non-ASP.NET 4.x apps (PHP, ASP.NET Core and so on), you can set "No Managed Code" to remove all the troubles.

Comment: I see, but..does it actually load that supporting libraries? You wrote "IIS tried to load". I'll run some tests to better understand it... My point is that should be transparent, but instead, you know,  it's more like toggling bad/good modes with no functional advantage.